# onPreviewFrame returning wrong byte[] length

Tags: android

I've trying to get byte-array and copy from there to another array some rows of picture previewing whith `onPreviewFrame()`. So I prepare Camera and new byte-array

```
        try {
        if (cam != null) {

            Camera.Parameters parameters = cam.getParameters();
            parameters.setPreviewFrameRate(25);
            parameters.setPictureFormat(ImageFormat.JPEG);
            cam.setParameters(parameters);
            cam.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            cam.startPreview();

            arr = new byte[(parameters.getPreviewSize().height)
                    * (parameters.getPreviewSize().width)];

            Log.i("" + parameters.getPictureSize().height, "   "
                    + parameters.getPictureSize().width);


        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("CAMERA", e.getMessage());
    }
```

And Log tell's me :

`480   640`

So `arr.length = 307200`

But:

```
public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {    
    Log.i(arr.length+" ",data.length+"");
}
```

`arr.length = 307200`
(which of course means Frame Size = 640*480)

but 
  `data.length = 460800`
(and it means Frame Size = 800*576)

And when I try to copy Data to Arr with `System.arraycopy(data, 0, arr, 0, arr.length);` and then export picture:

```
FileOutputStream outStream = null;
    try {
        outStream = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/new.jpg");

        Camera.Parameters parameters = cam.getParameters();
        Size size = parameters.getPreviewSize();

        YuvImage image = new YuvImage(arr, parameters.getPreviewFormat(),
                size.width, size.height, null);
        image.compressToJpeg(
                new Rect(0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight()), 90,
                outStream);

        outStream.flush();
        outStream.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.d("CAMERA", e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("CAMERA", e.getMessage());
    }
```

Picture become green:

[image]

So what I need to do to make data-array become 640*480? Or maybe you know another way to get single row from (for example) Bitmap and add it to another Bitmap?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct array size is
`new byte[previewSize.height * previewSize.width * (ImageFormat.getBitsPerPixel(parameters.getPreviewFormat())) / 8];` (different formats have different bits-per-pixel values, get them with [ImageFormat.getBitsPerPixel](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ImageFormat.html#getBitsPerPixel%28int%29))